# How do I execute a bulk `INSERT IGNORE` with Entity Framework Extensions library

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, insert, entity-framework-6

I'm trying to insert a large set of objects into the table but I don't have any efficient way to check if some records aren't already there. Every time I use this:

```
using Z.EntityFramework.Extensions.Core;
...
await ac.BulkInsertAsync(query, (o) => { o.?? });
```

it just stops the insert each time it finds a duplicate. Is there a way to either run all queries at once without it just stopping at the first error, or outright applying `IGNORE`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should check the **InsertIfNotExists** options. Only records that don't already exists will be inserted.

```
using Z.EntityFramework.Extensions.Core;
...
await ac.BulkInsertAsync(query, (o) => { o.InsertIfNotExists = true });
```

**ANSWER Sub-Question**

> I have an UNIQUE key in my table on one of the fields. How do I set it for bulk operations?

You can customize the key with the **ColumnPrimaryKeyExpression** option.

```
ctx.BulkInsert(list, options =>
{
    options.ColumnPrimaryKeyExpression = x => new { x.ColumnKey1, x.ColumnKey2 };
    options.InsertIfNotExists = true;
});
```

Comment: Right, I somehow missed this option before. Thanks!

Comment: Should it still be throwing the `Duplicate entry [...]` exception?

Comment: It should not, unless if the key in the database is not the same as the one you use for the BulkMerge. Do you still get the exception?

Comment: Yeah, I do. I have an `UNIQUE` key in my table on one of the fields. How do I set it for bulk operations?

Comment: It still doesn't seem to be working. I'm still getting `Duplicate entry 'R1550672' for key 'IX_UniversalId'` on this line: `await ac.BulkInsertAsync<UnifiedPost>(query, (o) => { o.ColumnPrimaryKeyExpression = p => new { p.Id, p.UniversalId }; o.InsertIfNotExists = true; });`

Comment: You use a key combination from p.Id and p.UniversalId, if I look at the index name, only UniversalId should be used perhaps?

Comment: If you can, contact me directly with this issue. I will try to help you out. Stack Overflow is not the best platform to provide support to my library ;)

Comment: Your library? Oh... Did I ever mention that I was using MySQL? Now I switched to SQL Server 2016 Express, which took me a few good hours to download and install but I finaly did. Now it works perfectly. One little, small, tiny question, though. How do I get the number of affected rows from this bulk query? I've seen the `options.AffectedRows` property there but I don't know how exactly to make use of it.

Comment: Oops! I forget to add a disclaimer. Yes, I'm the owner ;) The AffectedRows doesn't work currently. It works only for DeleteFromQuery && UpdateFromQuery features.

Comment: @JonathanMagnan - It looks like ColumnPrimaryKeyExpression is no longer an option?

Comment: @WEFX, ColumnPrimaryKeyExpression is still an option: https://dotnetfiddle.net/L1Wvep, could you let me know what is happening? It's optional on BulkInsert (if none is provided, we take the key mapped from the Entity Type)

Comment: I'm running a dotnet core app w/ EFCore.BulkExtensions and Z.BulkOperations package references.  Still, my compiler says, "BulkConfig' does not contain a definition for 'ColumnPrimaryKeyExpression'".  Same w/ InsertIfNotExists.

Comment: The library "EFCore.BulkExtensions" is not our library that's why ;) You can find links to download our library here: https://entityframework-extensions.net/download